# How to combine 2 matrix given a rule using numpy?

Tags: python, arrays, algorithm, numpy, matrix

I have two matrix.

```
a = [
  [1, 2, 3],
  [4, 5, 6],
  [7, 8, 9]
]
b = [
  [0, 0, 100],
  [100, 0, 0],
  [0, 0, 100]
]
```

I would like to create third matrix which contains elements from matrix `a` and non-zero elements from matrix `b`

```
c = [
  [1, 2, 100],
  [100, 5, 6],
  [7, 8, 100]
]
```

How can i do this using `numpy` ?
Thx!

Comment: What have you tried ? So is not a coding service ;) And in fact it's more : matrix b and zeros replaced by values from a

Comment: `np.where(b, b, a)` or `b[b==0] = a[b==0]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could index both arrays where `b==0`:

```
# this assumes a and b are NumPy arrays
m = b==0
b[m] = a[m]

print(b)
array([[  1,   2, 100],
       [100,   5,   6],
       [  7,   8, 100]])
```